# Fill NAs by multiple conditions on previous rows

Tags: r

I have large data frame, which contains transactions. The fields are id (user id), interval (integer from 0->), creation (date of transaction), expiry (date when subscription expires) and subscription (char of "one year" or "two years")
I'd need to modify the missing values in expiry based on few conditions based either on the same row or previous row.

```
df <- data.frame(id = id,
                 interval = interval,
                 creation = creation,
                 expiry = expiry,
                 subscription = subscription)
df <- df[order(df[, 1], df[, 3]),]

#loop all rows of ordered df (by subsID and payment date)
for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {
    # check NA of expiry
    if (is.na(df[i, 4])) { 
        #if previous row ID and interval match, we treat this as change to subscription
        if (df[i-1, 1] == df[i, 1] & df[i-1, 2] == df[i, 2]) {
            df[i, 4] <- df[i-1, 4]
        # otherwise it's one or two year new subscription so we add days to creation date
        } else if (df[i, 5] == "one year") {
            df[i, 4] <- df[i, 3] + 365
        } else if (df[i, 5] == "two years") {
            df[i, 4] <- df[i, 3] + 720
        }
     }
}
```

The code above does the trick, but leaves first NA empty and is very heavy to run to the point that with data frame on million rows it takes ages. How could I improve this and make it more R-like?

Comment: Could you provide a simulation of the data and what it looks like and how you would like it to look?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it might help you:

```
df <- data.frame(id = id,
                 interval = interval,
                 creation = creation,
                 expiry = expiry,
                 subscription = subscription)
df <- df[order(df[, 1], df[, 3]),]

library(dplyr)
df$match_previous <- (df[, 1] == lag(df[, 1]) & df[, 2] == lag(df[, 2]))
df$match_previous[1] <- FALSE
df[, 4] <- ifelse(!is.na(df[, 4]), 
                  df[, 4],
                  ifelse(df$match_previous,
                         lag(df[, 4]),
                         ifelse(df[, 5] == "one year",
                                df[, 3] + 365, df[, 3] + 730)))
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, your solution ended up working, but there were cases with multiple NAs in a row and match_previous = TRUE that the script would leave some NAs. However, by looping that _ifelse_ segment it got rid of all of them.